# capturing variable in curried arrow function

Tags: recursion, lambda, ecmascript-6, currying, arrow-functions

Arrow lambdas and other features in es6 simplifies write js in functional flavour, including currying
i was testing an implementation of `array map` but i faced a problem:
Here's my implementation:

```
let map = fn => a => a.length ?  [fn(a[0]), ...map(fn)(a.slice(1))]  : [];
let plus_10 = map(n => n+10);
plus_10([1,2,3]); // [11, 12, 13]
```

However this implementation recreates the  array_mapper function `...map(fn)` at each iteration

it would be nice to capture the array_mapper function and reference it in all iterations
this is a working implementation:

```
let map = fn => {
    let array_mapper = a => a.length ?  [fn(a[0]), ...array_mapper(a.slice(1))]  : [];
    return array_mapper;
};
```

but this brakes the fp's readability and neatness
i made, just to test, another *(albeit ugly)* implementation, but it is not syntax valid:

```
let map = fn => (let array_mapper = a => a.length ?  [fn(a[0]), ...array_mapper(a.slice(1))]  : [], array_mapper);
```

any clue?

*edit:*
a note about `...spread` performances:
testing this mapping functions in chrome with a 10000 sized array it takes 11 seconds!
but using `.concat` instead of the spread `...`

```
let map = fn => a => a.length ?  [fn(a[0])].concat(map(fn)(a.slice(1)))  : [];
```

exec time falls to 600ms

Comment: JavaScript already has a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

Comment: yep! sure, it's a pretext to explore es6 constructs